# Problema con uiGridConstants de ui-grid en Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aplicación-web

mi problema es al querer hacer el siguiente ejemplo de la documentacion de ui grid.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/113_adding_and_removing_columns

Especificamente esta funcion:

```
$scope.toggleVisible = function() {
    $scope.columns[0].visible = !($scope.columns[0].visible || $scope.columns[0].visible === undefined);
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
  }
```

Cuando ejecuta esta linea `$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);`

me dice que uiGridConstants es undefined, por lo cual no puedo lograr que la tabla se actualice.
Aclaro que inyecte uiGridConstants  en el controlador correspondiente

```
appAngular.controller('fillTableES', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$interval', '$rootScope', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $watch, $http, $log, $interval, $rootScope, uiGridConstants)
```

Gracias

Comment: `$watch` no es un inyectable sino una propiedad del `$rootScope` o el `$scope`

Comment: Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te sirvió.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes definido `$watch` los parametros del controlador.. asi los parametros no coninciden (recuerda se se aplican en orden, no por el nombre de la variable) y el servicio queda `undefined` (uno tiene 6 y el otro tiene 7).

Eliminalo de la lista de parametros, algo así:

```
appAngular.controller('fillTableES', 
        ['$scope', '$http', '$log', '$interval', '$rootScope', 'uiGridConstants', 
      function ($scope, $http, $log, $interval, $rootScope, uiGridConstants)
```

Saludos.